# DateTimeConverter on Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datetime, converters

how to get date from  (2012-10-10T 11:07:58:75   05:30) to (10/10/2012) . help me.

Comment: It's unclear what your input and desired output types are here. String to String, String to DateTime, DateTime to String?

Comment: Actually services returns to string 2012-10-10T 11:07:58:75 05:30 , from this string we want to get Date 10/10/2012

Comment: Are you sure it has the space after the T, and a space before the offset? I'd expect something like "2012-10-10T11:07:58:75-05:30" or "2012-10-10T11:07:58:75+05:30". Note that using `DateTimeOffset` would be a more informative representation than `DateTime`.

Comment: I can't understand how to convert date dd/mm/yyyy from  "2012-10-10T11:07:58:75+05:30"  DateTimeOffset Constructor have no string date argument

Comment: You'd use `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact`. Will add an answer to that effect...

Comment: DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("2012-10-10T10:07:58:75+05:30","dd/MM/yyyy",CurrentCulture.InvarientCulture.datetimeFormat)  gives Error Format Exception

Comment: Well yes, it would - because you're trying to parse it with the wrong format! You parse to a `DateTimeOffset`, and if you then want to *format* that to a different date, you need to use `ToString`. Parsing and formatting are two separate operations.

Answer (score 1):

Frist :  DateTime.ParseExact , Convert the string like "(2012-10-10T 11:07:58:75 05:30" To a
DateTime struct ---var d.

and d.tostring("your format")

Comment: if i use DateTime.ParseExact,it  returns back date

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you should be parsing to a `DateTimeOffset`, to represent all the data you've actually got:

```
string text = "2012-10-10T11:07:58+05:30";
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact
    (text, "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'sszzz",
     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

That assumes the final ":75" in your input string was actually a mistake. It's a *very* odd format. If it wasn't a mistake, you might want:

```
string text = "2012-10-10T11:07:58:75+05:30";
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact
    (text, "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss':'FFFzzz",
     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

That will handle up to 3 decimal places in the sub-millisecond range. If you ever have more than that, you can expand the pattern to up to 7 F characters.

When you want to obtain the date, you then need to determine whether you actually want the local date, or the date after converting to UTC. This will depend on your business requirements, but be aware of the effects. (Two values with the same local date may not represent the same 24 hour period of time.)

If you then want the value as a string again in a different format, you need a second step to format it, calling `ToString`. Given your sample which has the same day and month values, we unfortunately can't tell whether you want `MM/dd/yyyy` or `dd/MM/yyyy` - but you should really consider whether this should be culture-sensitive. If you can give us more context about how you're using this value, we can provide more suggestions.

Comment: both gives Format exception  why

Comment: Well it's still not clear exactly what your data is. Originally you specified it with a space after the T, but then in comments you seemed to accept my suggestion that it didn't have a T. Obviously you'll need to make the format fit your actual data.